# How to get a list of years of posts published for a specific category and children?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type and a custom taxonomy.
I need a list of years for which content has been published, filtered by a specific category which also includes all children.

Right now i can do it but without children:

```
$query_prepare = $wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT YEAR(post_date) 
            FROM $wpdb->posts AS p 
            INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON ( p.ID = tr.object_id)
            INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
            INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS t ON (t.term_id = tt.term_id)
            WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
            AND post_type = %s 
            AND t.slug = %s 
            GROUP BY YEAR(post_date)", $post_type, $cat);

        $years = $wpdb->get_results($query_prepare);
```

i don't know how to implement the code above or also to use WP_Query for this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a different approach.
From the taxonomy slug I get the ID.
Then the IDs of the child.
Then I query them in one shot.

```
$cat = 'your term slug';
$post_type = 'your post type';
define( 'VAL_TAXO', 'your taxonomy');

$term_obj = get_term_by('slug', $cat, VAL_TAXO);
$child_ids = get_term_children( $term_obj->term_id, VAL_TAXO );
array_push($child_ids, $term_obj->term_id);
$ids_txt = implode(',', $child_ids);

$query_prepare = $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT YEAR(post_date) 
    FROM $wpdb->posts  
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE 1=1
    AND ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (".$ids_txt.")) 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = %s 
    AND (($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'))
    GROUP BY YEAR(post_date)
        ", $post_type);
```